# What is $GL(n)$?

Tags: number-theory

I can't tell what this means. Im trying to read on automorphic forms outside of modular forms and I see sources talking about this $GL(n)$ thing and I have no reference to interpret this. The closest thing I've seen resembling $GL(n)$ in literature $GL(n, F)$.

Comment: "Algebra: A Graduate Course" by Isaacs has just about all the info on this you could ever want, and a bunch more, too.

Comment: @TheCount thanks you

Comment: In $GL(n,F)$ the scalar field is $F$.  The notation $GL(n)$ is the same, except that $F$ is not mentioned.  This could be because it is irrelevant, or because it is assumed known, or because it is specified earlier in the same paragraph/page/chapter...

Comment: Continuing @David's answer, when $F$ is not mentioned it's often assumed to be $\mathbb{R}$, or if not that, then $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Invertible $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: ^ there's your overall answer.

Comment: @TheCount how do i end this question. Do i close it?

Comment: Nah, you can just leave it. Perhaps @copper.hat would be willing to write a short answer and you can accept it.

Comment: @TheCount: You were first :-).

Comment: $\mathfrak{thanks guys}$

Comment: In the theory of algebraic groups GL(n) would mean "a group scheme", which is a functor from commutative rings to groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer as per request:

"Algebra: A Graduate Course" by Isaacs has just about all the info on this you could ever want, and a bunch more, too.